# Как распарсить JS средствами BeautifulSoup из bs4

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Распарсил **HTML**

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')  # content is a html page
info = soup.findAll('script')
```

Получил **JS** с необходимыми данными, примерно такого содержания:

```js
window.check = function(...) {
    ...
}
new.userData['old_info'] = '[{"name":"name", "sex":"sex", "limit":"limit},
                             {"name":"name", "sex":"sex", "limit":"limit},
                             {"name":"name", "sex":"sex", "limit":"limit}]'
```

Могу ли я достать инфо из переменной `new.userData['old_info']` средствами `bs`?

В доках по парсингу **JS** ничего не нашел. Подскажите подходящее решение, заранее благодарен.

Comment: что может стоять в строке `info` после `...]'`? Т.е. как можно однозначно отличить конец значения переменной `new.userData['old_info']`?

Comment: @MaxU вы уже регулярку обдумываете?)

Comment: @Alban, ну да ;)

Comment: @MaxU автор просит средствами bs

Comment: @Alban, не уверен, что BS это умеет...

Comment: @MaxU отредактировал вопрос, я не настаиваю на `bs`, но хотелось бы узнать побольше, как сделать правильно и производительно, раньше мало сталкивался с парсингом, тем более `js`

Comment: Вам стоит взглянуть на это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390992/javascript-parser-in-python

Comment: Как и сказал @Alban вот конкретная ссылка. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25112096/5004246 bs для прасинга HTML, а парсинга  JS из распарсеного HTML используется другой инструмент [slimit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```
import ast
import re

html = """
window.check = function(...) {
    ...
}
new.userData['old_info'] = '[{"name":"name", "sex":"sex", "limit":"limit"}]'
"""

match = re.search(r"new.userData\['old_info'\] = '(.+)'", html)
if match:
    old_info = ast.literal_eval(match.group(1))
    print(old_info)  # [{'name': 'name', 'limit': 'limit', 'sex': 'sex'}]
    print(old_info[0]['name'])  # name
```

Вместо `ast` можно попробовать `json`, только апострофы нужно будет на кавычки заменить